# Accessing Certificates from Emails under Outlook 2013

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, certificate, microsoft-outlook-2013

I am trying to add certificates to contacts from emails I receive. Normally you can click on the signed icon on the right, click on details, and then click on the view certificate button. In my particular instance however, all three of the buttons are greyed out. Obviously, there is a policy set incorrectly but I have no idea where. Can anyone help me? I am using Outlook 2013+

Comment: Does this issue only occur to the particular message? Have you already added the user into your contacts? Please go through the steps in the Step 3 section of the link below and see if the certificate can be added: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/get-a-digital-id-0eaa0ab9-b8a2-4a7e-828b-9bded6370b7b?ocmsassetID=HA102748952&CorrelationId=2ca1b304-9a65-4aff-a3bc-3e4e3c658237&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: This is on all of the emails I have tried so far.